# iam facing the error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Getallproducts, Line 66 Incorrect syntax near 'End'

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
create procedure sp_Getallproducts (@CatagoryID int)
--iam facing the problem in End     
    As BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    IF (@CatagoryID <> 0)
    Begin
    select * from (
    select p.Catagoryid,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productName,
            p.productprice,
            p.productImageurl,
            c.catagory_name,
            p.productquntatiy,
            Isnull(Sum (cp.TotalProduct),0) As productsold,
            (p.productquntatiy - isnull (sum(cp.TotalProduct),0)) AS AvilableStock

            from Products p
            INNER JOIN catagory c ON
            c.Catagory_id = p.Catagoryid
                LEFT JOIN Customerproducts
                cp on cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
                Group by

    p.Catagoryid,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productName,
            p.productprice,
            p.productImageurl,
            c.catagory_name,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productquntatiy,
            p.Catagoryid)StockTable 
            where avilableStock > 0 AND Catagoryid = @CatagoryID
    End 
    ELSE
     BEGIN
     select * from (
    select p.Catagoryid,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productName,
            p.productprice,
            p.productImageurl,
            c.catagory_name,
            p.productquntatiy,
            Isnull(Sum (cp.TotalProduct),0) As productsold,
            (p.productquntatiy - isnull (sum(cp.TotalProduct),0)) AS AvilableStock

            from Products p
            INNER JOIN catagory c ON
            c.Catagory_id = p.Catagoryid
                LEFT JOIN Customerproducts
                cp on cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
                Group by

    p.Catagoryid,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productName,
            p.productprice,
            p.productImageurl,
            c.catagory_name,
            p.ProductID,
            p.productquntatiy,
            p.Catagoryid)StockTable 
            where avilableStock > 0
            End 

            End
            TRY
```

Comment: you are missing `BEGIN CATCH`, `END CATCH` and `END` of the procedure

Comment: You should also be aware [of this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Answer (score 0):

There is no `catch` block. See this:

> A TRY block must be immediately followed by an associated CATCH block.
>   Including any other statements between the END TRY and BEGIN CATCH
>   statements generates a syntax error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx